# Skipping validation on building a related object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Within my app, when a new User is created, the Profile is automatically built:

```
  before_create :build_default_profile

  protected

    def build_default_profile
      build_profile
      true
    end
```

I would like to skip validations on that profile, and remain thread-safe. I tried *validate: false, and .send(:create_without_callbacks)* - both unsuccessfully. I also could go with filling my Profile with dummy data, but that seems like a lot of hassle. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: You wouldn't want to save a profile with no data in it?

Comment: it also possible to write the same code shorter. just `before_create :build_profile` without protected method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish it helps

```
# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile
  validates :username, presence: true unless new_record?
end


# app/models/user.rb
class User
  before_create :build_profile
end
```